# Can ZFC define every function and relation that PA can define, plus more?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, peano-axioms

Can ZFC define every n-ary function and relation on the natural numbers that Peano Arithmetic can define, plus more? If so, what is the proof, and also, can someone give an example of a number theoretic function or relation that ZFC can define but PA can't.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ZFC is more powerful and contains PA , so ZFC can prove everything PA can prove. Also ZFC can formulate everything PA can formulate.